# How to use htaccess file for subdirectory url

Tags: .htaccess

My problem is to redirect from subdirectory link to one file.
my current url

```
www.sample.com/stream/34/video.m3u8
www.sample.com/stream/35/video.m3u8
```

hope

```
www.sample.com/stream.php?param1=35&param2=video.m3u8
```

or

```
www.sample.com/stream/index.php?param1=35&param2=video.m3u8
```

Please save my life

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following using mod_rewrite in the root `.htaccess` file in order to rewrite the request to `/stream.php?param1=<id>&param2=<file>`:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^stream/(\d+)/([\w-]+\.\w{2,4})$ stream.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L]
```

This assumes that the `<id>` (2nd path segment) is entirely numeric and the 3rd path segment consists of `<filename>.<ext>`. You should restrict this to `m3u8` if that is all you are expecting.